# Classicthesis/arsclassica ToC section numbers too wide (and incoherent font)

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, width, classicthesis

Desired result:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{classicthesis}
%\usepackage{arsclassica}

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    \setcounter{chapter}{10}
    \chapter{Some chapter}
    \section{Some section}

\end{document}
```

[image: desired result]

---

In the following example the section number in ToC is too close to the section title (due to `microtype`'s tracking):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{classicthesis}
%\usepackage{arsclassica}

\microtypesetup{tracking=true}

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    \setcounter{chapter}{10}
    \chapter{Some chapter}
    \section{Some section}

\end{document}
```

[image: microtype's tracking]

---

The same applies to both chapter and section ToC entries a similar example without tracking:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{classicthesis}
%\usepackage{arsclassica}

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    \setcounter{chapter}{100}
    \chapter{Some chapter}
    \section{Some section}

\end{document}
```

[image: too long section number]

---

Also, when `classicthesis` is changed to `arsclassica`, another strange behavior is observed – font is incoherent for the first ToC character:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

%\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    \setcounter{chapter}{10}
    \chapter{Some chapter}
    \section{Some section}

\end{document}
```

[image: incoherent fonts]

---

How can I get sufficient width of chapter/section/… fields (boxes?) in ToC without giving up `microtype`'s tracking and also possibly get rid of font inconsistency in `arsclassica`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that André Miede, the author of `classicthesis`, mentioned in the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/ClassicThesis.pdf):

> **Page 6**: As a new feature, Lorenzo Pantieri’s `arsclassica` is available as well. As Lorenzo’s package is discontinued and with his permission, `classicthesis-arsclassica.sty` is now part of `classicthesis` and will be maintained here.

So you may now write

```
\usepackage[style=arsclassica]{classicthesis}
```

to access the `arsclassica` style.

## Font incoherence is caused by `classicthesis`’s implementation

The ToC is customized via the `tocloft` package. In particular, the chapter number is affected by this line in [`classicthesis.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/classicthesis.sty):

```
% from `classicthesis'
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\spacedlowsmallcaps}%
```

where `\spacedlowsmallcaps` is defined by

```
% from `classicthesis'
% engine-dependent letterspacing
% if engine = pdfLaTeX, then
\DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedlowsmallcaps}[1]{\textls[80]{\ct@caps\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}
% if engine = XeLaTeX, then
\DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedlowsmallcaps}[1]{{\addfontfeatures{LetterSpace=14.0}\ct@caps\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}% WordSpace=1.8
```

This has really bad interaction with how `tocloft` redefines `\numberline`:

```
% from `tocloft'
\let\@cftbsnum \cftchappresnum
...
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{% 
  \hb@xt@\@tempdima{\@cftbsnum #1\@cftasnum\hfil}\@cftasnumb}
```

It should be clear now that *during macro expansion only the leftmost character of `#1` is grabbed by `\spacedlowsmallcaps`*. So when `\ct@altfont` becomes `\sffamily` in the `arsclassica` style, only the first digit becomes sans-serif.

A quick fix is to redefine `\numberline` again by putting that `#1` in a pair of `{}`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[style=arsclassica]{classicthesis}

% redefine \numberline again
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{% 
  \hb@xt@\@tempdima{\@cftbsnum{#1}\@cftasnum\hfil}\@cftasnumb}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    \setcounter{chapter}{14}% changed for illustration
    \chapter{Some chapter}
    \section{Some section}

\end{document}
```

[image: font consistent]

This is definitely a bug, I shall report this issue on [André Miede’s website](https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/issues).

## Additional space in ToC after chapter number

**Edited**: Writing `\microtypesetup{tracking=true}` is NOT recommended! The `classicthesis` package has its own engine-dependent way of dealing with letter-spacing. This is implemented by `\spacedallcaps` and `\spacedlowsmallcaps`. In short, *the package already uses tracking*.

[Tracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter-spacing) is meant to increase the inter-letter spacing between small capitals. So the cramped space after the chapter number is to be expected. Again, after a quick read through the `classicthesis` [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/ClassicThesis.pdf), we find:

> **Page 7**: `manychapters`: if you need more than nine chapters for your document, you might not be happy with the spacing between the chapter number and the chapter title in the Table of Contents …

However, simply writing

```
\usepackage[manychapters]{classicthesis}
```

is not satisfactory. So we can borrow and modify the code from [`classicthesis.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/classicthesis.sty):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{classicthesis}

\settowidth{\newchnumberwidth}{00} % <--- tweak here if more space required
\addtolength{\cftchapnumwidth}{\newchnumberwidth}%
\addtolength{\cftsecnumwidth}{\newchnumberwidth}
\addtolength{\cftsecindent}{\newchnumberwidth}
\addtolength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{\newchnumberwidth}
\addtolength{\cftsubsecindent}{2\newchnumberwidth}
\addtolength{\cftsubsubsecnumwidth}{\newchnumberwidth}

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    \setcounter{chapter}{100}
    \chapter{Some chapter}
    \section{Some section}

\end{document}
```

[image: more space]

Comment: Interesting, everything seems to be up to date, e.g., `classicthesis` v4.6, `arsclassica` ver. 11/01/2017, but the first ToC character still seems to be from different font family. I also observe the same behavior on another machine, both using MiKTeX (with freshly updated packages) on Windows 10. It persists after switching to `\usepackage[style=arsclassica]{classicthesis}`.

Comment: @Peter Thank you for telling me! My further investigation led to the discovery of an apparent bug of `classicthesis`. Please check my updated answer. I think there must be some better way to implement tracking. In your case, using `\microtypesetup{tracking=true}` will cause “double tracking”, which is wrong. I don’t know if the current `\textls[...]{}` or `\addfontfeatures{LetterSpace=...}` implementation could be improved.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following helps:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

%\usepackage{classicthesis}

\usepackage{arsclassica}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\scshape\MakeTextLowercase}

\microtypesetup{tracking=true}

\settowidth{\newchnumberwidth}{\cftchappresnum 99}
\addtolength{\cftchapnumwidth}{\newchnumberwidth}%
\addtolength{\cftsecnumwidth}{\newchnumberwidth}
\addtolength{\cftsecindent}{\newchnumberwidth}
\addtolength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{\newchnumberwidth}
\addtolength{\cftsubsecindent}{2\newchnumberwidth}
\addtolength{\cftsubsubsecnumwidth}{\newchnumberwidth}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{chapter}{100}
\chapter{Some chapter}
\section{Some section}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah… I was too focused on quoting from the package documentation to realize you posted an answer before me. However, I decide to keep my answer as it adds additional information on the subject. :)